# Inverse of absolute value function $f(x)=1+x|x|$

Tags: functions, absolute-value, inverse-function

I'm trying to find the inverse of the function
$$ f(x)=1+x|x| $$

I tried to do this:
$$ 
y=1+x|x|
\\x=1+y|y|
\\y|y|=x-1
\\(y|y|)^2=(x-1)^2
\\y^4=(x-1)^2
\\y=\sqrt{x-1}$$

which I believe is wrong because the domain of the function includes negative numbers, while $\sqrt{x-1}$ is always positive.

What is the correct inverse of the function and how to find it?

Comment: Have you graphed the function to get an intuition for what the inverse looks like?

Comment: I recommend you to get rid of absolute value by splitting the original function into two cases: when $x<0$ and when $x\ge 0$

Comment: @JalexStark I have

Comment: @saulspatz I switched the roles of x and y

Comment: Perhaps by now, you can see an answer already. Otherwise, I may post one with a **minimum** of explaining. Indeed, more words would only obscure the reader's own thinking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A bit of detail:

Let $D_f= \mathbb{R}$.

1) Check if $f(x) = 1+x|x|$ has an inverse.

$f_{\ge}(x):= f(x) = 1+x^2$ , for $x\ge 0$, strictly increasing .

$f_{\lt}(x)=f(x) = 1-x^2$ , for $x\lt 0$ , strictly decreasing.

2) Now you invert $f_{\ge}$ and $f_{\lt}$,

(User Mohammad).

Answer (score 1):

Your calculations are valid for $x>1$

Note that $$f(x)=1+x|x|=\begin {cases} 1+x^2 \text{,  if x>0}\\1-x^2 \text {, if $x\le 0$}\end {cases}$$

therefore, $$ f^{-1}(x) = =\begin {cases} \sqrt {x-1} \text{,  if x>1}\\\sqrt {1-x} \text {, if $x\le 1$}\end {cases}$$